# How to parse URL in Markdown gracefully by shell?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a Markdown text like this:

```
this is a [sample1](http://sample1.com/) link.
this is a [sample2](http://sample2.com/) link.
this is a [sample3](http://sample3.com/) link.
...
```

I want to output every link like this:

```
sample1 http://sample1.com
sample2 http://sample2.com
sample3 http://sample3.com
```

But my code is very messy (used `grep`, `sed`, `awk` and some pipe)...

How to do this gracefully ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 sed -rn 's@^.*\[(.*)\]\((.*)/.*$@\1 \2@p'
```

Using @ as the sed separator, focus on the data in brackets and print them with \1 and \2

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(.*\[)(.*)(\]\()(http:.+)(\/\) link)
```

[See it here](https://regex101.com/r/j1fKwY/1)